# Get the value of the Item in the Listview

Tags: android, android-listview

I have an array of Strings i.e.
String [] values ={"Adult 1","Adult 2","Child 1","Child 2","Infant 1","Infant 1"};

With this array I am creating a listView .
On click on a listview item, I am opening a custom dialog that have 2 edit text and on TextView.

So click on the item I want to set the value of edit text with the value of item, if it is not  Adult, Child or Infant.

And I also want to check - if the item is not adult, I have to set the visibility of textview in the custom dialog visible.

How could I do this?

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
        int position, long id) {
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For getting the values u can do something like this

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
            String  itemValue = ((TextView) view).getText().toString();


            }
        });
```

for checking a string whether it contains or not try dis

```
str1.toLowerCase().contains(str2.toLowerCase())
```

Comment: how colud i check the text value is similar to Adult or Child because 1,2 will be dynamic